# Rename xml tag for tag with same name on same level

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, parsing, xpath

My project needs to convert xml to rename tag which have the same name as other tag on same level.
I try to use the function docucment.renameNode(), but it seems not working... The difficulty is how identify the correct tag to rename.

Exemple, here the source xml :

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C></C>
  </B>
  <B>
    <D>
      <E></E>
    </D>
  </B>
  <B>
    <F></F>
  </B>
</A>
```

Here the new expected xml :

```
<A>
  <B_1>
    <C></C>
  </B_1>
  <B_2>
    <D>
      <E></E>
    </D>
  </B_2>
  <B_3>
    <F></F>
  </B_3>
</A>
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to help if you add your code even if it is currently not working.

Comment: Do you mean java or (javascript for webdevelopment)?

Comment: @Huhngut I mean java language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you want to do this conversion: Putting sequence numbers into tag names is generally considered a bad idea, since it usually makes the XML harder to process subsequently.

But if you really want to do it, it's a very straightforward XSLT transformation. In XSLT 3.0 it's

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="B">
    <xsl:element name="B_{count(preceding-sibling::B)+1}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It's also easy enough with XSLT 1.0, just a few more lines of code to add an identity template in place of the xsl:mode declaration. Still a lot easier than hand-coding it in Java.